# Deleting Record And Refreshing Won't Work Consistently

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I have a webpage with a table of data where the user can delete some records . Once he deletes a record (by sending a delete request with ajax) I want to reflect that change by reloading the page(expecting that the deleted record won't come back from my controller and thus won't be repopulated in the table) . However , annoyingly , it doesn't consistently work : I sometimes still see the record in the table (although it was deleted from the database) and only when I manually refresh the page the record is gone . I'm not sure if this is due to a delay in my server (php & mysql hosted on godaddy) or something with the connection (it's worse on a slow connection) . I've even added 4 seconds timeout before reloading the page but it still won't consistently work.
This is the code :

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php  echo site_url("/developer/delete/")?>',
            data: { "pluginId" : e.target.parentNode.parentNode.id},

            }).done(setTimeout(location.reload(),4000));
```

Has anyone ever stumbled upon a similar problem ?

Comment: If you want to reload your page - why use AJAX then?

Comment: Well I want to reload the page only when the delete operation has finished ... I could make it a regular non ajax request but this will still happen I suspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the location.reload() gets the page from cache.  Using location.reload(true) should force the page to get the latest information from the server.